# Bash script to replace matched substrings within larger substring

Tags: string, bash, replace

I'm trying to write a bash script to replace the newline characters and `*`s from comments, but only if that comment contains a particular substring.

```
// file.txt
/**
 * Here is a multiline
 * comment that contains substring
 * rest of it
 */

/**
 * Here is a multiline
 * comment that does not contain subNOTstring
 * rest of it
 */
```

I would like the final result to be:

```
// file.txt
/** Here is a multiline comment that contains substring rest of it */

/**
 * Here is a multiline
 * comment that does not contain subNOTstring
 * rest of it
 */
```

I have a regex that matches multiline comments: `\/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*\/]|[\r\n])))*\*\/` but can't figure out the second part, of only matching with the substring, and then replacing all the `/n *`  with just

So to make sure my question is articulated correctly

1. Make a match of a substring within a file. i.e. comment
2. Make sure that match includes `substring`.
3. Replace all substring within the first match with another string. i.e. `n/ *` with

Comment: I wouldn't do this multiline matching in bash. Perhaps `sed` would be an option, or awk or some more flexible programming language (Ruby, Perl). In any case, your approach would fail if the character sequence `/**` occurs in a context where it does not denote the start of a comment. I don't know about the general syntax of your file, but this would apply for instance to C or PL/1 source code.

Comment: @user1934428 sed works in bash so that would be an acceptable solution.  I just need to be able to run a *.sh file and have it do the thing.

Answer (score 1):

If `python` is your option, would you please try:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re                                                       # use regex module

with open('file.txt') as f:                                     # open "file.txt" to read
    str = f.read()                                              # assign "str" to the lines of the file

for i in re.split(r'(/\*.*?\*/)', str, flags=re.DOTALL):        # split the file on the comment including the comment in the result
    if re.match(r'/\*.*substring', i, flags=re.DOTALL):         # if the comment includes the keyword "substring"
        i = re.sub(r'\n \* |\n (?=\*/)', ' ', i)                # then replace the newline and the asterisk with a whitespace
    print(i, end='')                                            # print the element without adding newline
```

- `re.split(r'(/\*.*?\*/)', str, flags=re.DOTALL)` splits "str" on the comment
  including the comment in the splitted list.
- The `flags=re.DOTALL` option makes a dot match with newline characters.
- `for i in ..` syntax loops over the list assiging "i" to each element.
- `re.match(r'/\*.*substring', i, flags=re.DOTALL)` matches the element
  which is a comment including the keyword "substring".
- `re.sub(r'\n \* |\n (?=\*/)', ' ', i)` replaces a newline followed by
  the " * " in the next line with a whitespace.
- `\n (?=\*/)` is a positive lookahead which matches a newline followed
  by " */". It will match the last line of the comment block leaving the
  "*/" as is.

**[Edit]**
If you want to embed the python script in bash, would you please try:

```
#!/bin/bash

infile="file.txt"                       # modify according to your actual filename
tmpfile=$(mktemp /tmp/temp.XXXXXX)      # temporary file to output

# start of python script
python3 -c "
import re, sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
with open(filename) as f:
    str = f.read()

for i in re.split(r'(/\*.*?\*/)', str, flags=re.DOTALL):
    if re.match(r'/\*.*substring', i, flags=re.DOTALL):
        i = re.sub(r'\n \* |\n (?=\*/)', ' ', i)
    print(i, end='')
" "$infile" > "$tmpfile"
# end of python script

mv -f -- "$infile" "$infile".bak        # backup the original file
mv -f -- "$tmpfile" "$infile"           # replace the input file with the output
```

Comment: If python were an option OP would have included it in the tags. Downvoted

Comment: I think I can make this work by just calling the python from the bash script.  Expect that it is just printing the result instead of saving it over the original file.txt.  How would I make it save over the original.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. You're right. The posted python script just prints the output without replacing the original file. I've updated my answer with another version which embeds the python script in bash and overwrites the original file. BR.